# Orthonormal coordinate coframe in arbitrary Riemannian manifold - question on published paper

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, coordinate-systems

In Miranda Jr, Pallara, Paronetto and Preunkert's [Heat semigroup and functions of bounded variation on Riemannian manifolds](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marc-Preunkert/publication/243112016_Heat_semigroup_and_functions_of_bounded_variation_on_Riemannian_manifolds/links/542c23e30cf29bbc126b71e5/Heat-semigroup-and-functions-of-bounded-variation-on-Riemannian-manifolds.pdf) (p.106, property (4)), the authors state that for an $n\ge 2$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ without boundary, one can construct a collection of coordinate charts $(U_i^\eta,\psi_i)$ such that $T^*(U_i^\eta)\simeq U_i^\eta \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and $d\psi_i$ is an isometry between $T^*_x(M)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for every $x \in U_i^\eta$.

Why is this possible when $M$ is not flat? The coordinate system $(U_i^\eta, \psi_i)$ seems to have an orthonormal coordinate frame, which is only possible if $M$ has a flat metric on $M$ (by e.g. Theorem 13.14 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539577/is-a-riemannian-manifold-with-isometric-coordinate-charts-flat)).

*Miranda, M. jun.; Pallara, D.; Paronetto, F.; Preunkert, M.*, [**Heat semigroup and functions of bounded variation on Riemannian manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/CRELLE.2007.093), J. Reine Angew. Math. 613, 99-119 (2007). [ZBL1141.58014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1141.58014).

Answer (score 0):

The existence of a local isometry implies flatness, since the curvature tensor is a local invariant. So this condition implies $(M, g)$ is flat on the neighborhood of interest.

One can arrange for coordinate charts to be an isometry at *one* point and have all first derivatives of the metric vanish *at that point* - these are called exponential coordinates - but no better is possible in general. It is likely the case (but one should check) that only this or something similar which can be arranged for using previously assumed hypotheses is actually used in the proofs involving this condition.

Comment: The proof seems to use the fact for all points $x$ in the neighbourhood. To get from their first to their second formula for $|Dv|(U_i^\eta)$ on page 107, they seem to use the fact $|\omega|=|w|$ where $w_j:=g(\omega,dx^j)$.

Comment: The map $\omega \mapsto g(\omega, dx^j)\partial_j$ appears to just be a way of writing a musical isomorphism, and the norm equality shouldn't need the isometry condition. Upon looking a bit closer, the steps taken on this page look from a distance like adjustments are being made for the pullback being non-isometric.

Comment: Why doesn't the norm equality need an isometry condition? If the metric was $\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, then we'd have $|\omega|=3$ and $|w|=2$.